# WPF MultiComboBox Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I created this comboBox with checkbox-items for multiselection.

```
<ComboBox  Height="25"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="MultiComboBox1" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" Width="240" Margin="25 0 0 0" >                            
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Name="checkBoxMulti" Width="224"  IsChecked="{Binding Check_Status}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item_ID}"
                                              Height="15" Content="{Binding Item_Name}" Checked="checkBoxMulti_Checked" Unchecked="checkBoxMulti_Unchecked">
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
```

But im struggling to make a style out of it.

```
<Style x:Key="MultiComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTextSearchEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnEdit" Value="True"/>            
            <Style.Resources>
                <ComboBox x:Key="ComboBox" x:Name="ComboBoxMulti">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  Name="checkBox" Width="224" IsChecked="{Binding Check_Status}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item_ID}"
                                              Height="15" Content="{Binding Item_Name}">
                                <!--Checked="checkBoxMulti_Checked" Unchecked="checkBoxMulti_Unchecked">-->                               
                            </CheckBox>                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
```

The combobox items are not checkboxes and it doesnt show the values from "Item_Name".
Also i dont now where to use the Checked and Unchecked Events.
I have to use the multicombobox a lot, so i want to use it as a style.

Comment: Why is there a ComboBox resource in a Style targeting ComboBox? That makes no sense. You want to have a Setter for the ItemTemplate property, just like the other setters.

Comment: For the event handlers, you do not need them. Just react on selection changes in the setter of the Check_Status view model property.

Comment: Thanks, your advice helped me a lot, now its working :)

Comment: @Clemens Im tying to set the values from the selected CheckBoxes in the Content of the Combobox, to see what is selected. When the checkBox_Checked Method is called i want to change the content of the combobox, but i need the name of the Combobox that includes the checkbox. Do you know a way i can get the name of the combobox from the checkbox. Something like getParentElement